# Discarding first column of a data set in R

Tags: arrays, r, csv, read.table

I want to read 300 *.csv  format arrays discarding first row and first column. I know if I use "header=TRUE" in "read.csv" it would not consider the first row. For example:

```
  mydta.without.first.row <- read.csv("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\myarray.csv",header=FALSE)
```

Is there any argument that I can use and discard the first column as well?

Comment: Read it in and then use `mydta[,-1]` to drop the first column.  You might also be able to use `colClasses=c("NULL",...)` (but then you have to specify all the other column classes explicitly)

Comment: What's wrong with dropping the first column once it's loaded?

Comment: You could Bens solution in one line too:  mydta.without.first.row <- read.csv("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\myarray.csv")[-1,-1]

Comment: @ Senor O; I have 300 data sets.

Comment: @user2607526 well lucky for you R is a programming language...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can load your 300 data sets in a list :

I would first put all my .csv files in a directory, and then :

```
gdir <- "dir-containing-your-300-files"
fn <- list.files(gdir, pattern="*.csv", full.names=F)
ldf <- lapply(fn, function(x) read.csv(x,header=F)[-1,-1])
```

You'l end up with a list of 300 data.frames without the first row and column. Each list element will have a name (your file names) attach to it.

If you want to write the new data.frames in files (with new.filename.csv as file names).

```
mapply(write.table,x=ldf,file=paste("new",fn,sep="."),MoreArgs=list(row.names=F,col.names=F,sep=","))
```

This will write new files, so you won't erase any of your original ones. 
You might have to tweak the command to suit your need.

Comment: @ Chargaff; Does it rewrite new data sets on the old one? Because I did what you have mentioned above and it didn't work.

Comment: @SaZa What didn't work ? The solution I provided doesn't write anything, it loads your data sets into a list. If you want to write each elements of your list afterwards, use something like lapply(ldf,write.table). There might be a better solution if your goal is to rewrite your files, but mine should work.

Comment: @SaZa Do you need to work on your data.frames with R after you read them ? Or is the only task you want to do with R is remove the first columns,row ?

Comment: @ Chargaff; Yes I just want to remove the first columns.

Comment: @SaZa I edited my answer so you could write your new data.frames in different files.